# need only do / only need to do

Tags: semi-modals

As I understand it, all the sentences are fine. I can't understand why in the second sentence we don't say "need only to do", but in the third we do (only need to do). Could you explain it, please?

> It needs (that) good people to do nothing. (need=require (an ordinary verb))
>
> For it, good people **need only do** nothing. (need = must (a modal verb))
>
> For it, good people **only need to do** nothing. (need = must (a modal verb))

Comment: Note that ***It needs that** [required condition]* is not idiomatically valid in English. And even if preceding text clearly defines exactly what pronoun "it" refers back to, it's very unlikely a native Anglophone would say ***For it**, [required condition]*. The closest you might encounter would be ***For it to happen...*** (or feasibly, ***For that...***, which allows speaker to place heavy stress on the determiner ***that***, which would normally be required in such contexts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, I answered a question you had about a truncated quotation from Edmund Burke, who wrote in the literary style of the eighteenth century. Now you seem to be playing around with examples that you have made up to try to grasp Burke's grammar. None of your examples are idiomatic, and one is outright not grammatical.

Sometimes "need" is used as a synonym for "require." In those usages, the grammar of "need" and "require" are the same.

> Babies need [require] milk.

Basic English structure: noun as a subject, followed by a verb, followed by a noun as an object. Of course, nouns may be supplemented by articles or adjectives or replaced by pronouns or clauses.

> The baby needs [requires] a warm blanket.

This is basic English grammar.

> I need [require] that frying pan.

"That" is being used as a demonstrative adjective, also called a determiner.

It is grammatical to have a clause as the object of "need"

> I need that you find the license.

There "that" is being used as a subordinate conjunction to introduce a clause replacing a noun. But that is not usual. What is usual is to find a phrase containing an infinitive replacing the noun.

> I need you to find the license.

That is the more idiomatic way to express that thought.

Now if you insist on a clause, it must be a proper clause with subject and verb.

> It needs that good people to do nothing

is not grammatical. The verb in that clause has been displaced by an infinitive.

> It needs that good people do nothing

is grammatical although rare and (without the quotation from Burke in mind) opaque.

> It needs good people to do nothing

is grammatical and idiomatic (though still opaque without reference to Burke).

You are correct that "need" is also used as a synonym for "must." A folk saying is "Needs must."

The grammar differs slightly. "Must" takes the bare infinitive. "Need" takes the to-infinitive.

> I must call

> I need to call.

Now for "only."

> X only needs Y

and

> X needs only Y

mean the same thing: Y is necessary and sufficient to cause X. The second form is more emphatic.

And finally, for those who do not see the relationship between your question yesterday about a specific quotation and your question today, your examples starting with "for" must seem very strange.

"For evil to triumph" makes sense as an introduction to a sentence. "For it" is simply too abbreviated to be construed.

**EDIT**: It turns out that I did not fully grasp the intent of the OP’s question with reference to “only need” and “need only.” It arose out of comments made to a different question that I answered a day or so ago and to answers to a years-old question on the English Usage and Language site. I shall try to address the basics in this edit.

I said above that when “need” is used as a synonym for “must,” there is this grammatical difference: “must” takes a bare infinitive whereas “need” takes a “to” infinitive.

That is correct, at least in modern American English, although it ignores some complications.

> I must make a phone call

and

> I need to make a phone call

are grammatical whereas

> I must to make a phone call

and

> I need make a phone call

are not grammatical. I am not a historian of English grammar, but it would not surprise me to learn that previously “need” was sometimes treated as a full modal parallel to “will,” “can,” or “must” without the necessity for a to-infinitive. But, today in the US, “I need go potty” is baby talk, not normal usage. “I need **to** go to the bathroom” is normal adult usage.

But here is where things begin to go off the rails. The question I answered yesterday was about literary language from the eighteenth century. Furthermore, it is true that in modern US English and in older forms of English, it is grammatical to use a bare infinitive with “need” in some circumstances.

> You need only sign the first page

is grammatical. I’d argue based on personal experience that the construction is rare in the US today, but it is grammatical. Far more common today are

> You need to sign only the first page

and

> You only need to sign the first page

In the ELU post cited in the comments below, there is a long discussion about when the to-infinitive is not required with “need” in modern English. I shall not attempt to intrude on that discussion. Nor can that discussion determine how authors combined “need” and infinitives in centuries gone by. The only simple answer I can give is this

**You will seldom if ever go wrong by using the to-infinitive in conjunction with “need” as a synonym for “must,” but a bare infinitive is permissible in certain contructions.**

Comment: Your answer is great, I have understood your message completely. My question about "only" was relied on the following: "In this setting, we **need only consider** X. We could equivalently say:  In this setting, **we only need to consider** X.
I agree that the second is more common, but would submit that the first is not incorrect." https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103230/need-to-do-vs-need-do

Comment: As I understand you, you don't think that "only" can add or remove "to". So, that person did a mistake?

Comment: And also ColleenV wrote yesteday: It could be "The triumph of evil **needs good people to do** nothing." or "For evil to triumph, **good people need only do** nothing (refrain from acting)." https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294740/the-only-thing-necessary-for-the-triumph-of-evil-is-for-good-men-to-do-nothing?noredirect=1#comment548661_294740

Comment: I was certainly not intending to disagree with @ColleenV or the folks at ELU. I have tried to clarify my intent with an edit to my answer.